# Can't connect to Cosmos to query Hive server using JDBC client, used to work until today

Tags: fiware-cosmos

Has anything changed on the Cosmos public instance or maybe the hive server is down?

Thanks!

M.S

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still experiencing the same issue but, this might be helpful for others who bump into your question.

Yes, there have been changes to the Cosmos public instance, there is a new Hadoop cluster now. You should move your data to the new storage cluster and run your hive queries through the computing cluster.

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cosmos/blob/develop/doc/manuals/quick_start_guide_new.md) guide for more information and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413460/ssh-access-for-the-headnode-of-fiware-cosmos) StackOverflow question might also be helpful.