# SSH access for the headnode of FIWARE-Cosmos

Tags: hadoop, hive, fiware, fiware-cosmos

I am following [this](http://fiware-cosmos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_and_programmer_manual/batch/using_hadoop_and_ecosystem/index.html#section2) guide on Hadoop/FIWARE-Cosmos and I have a question about the Hive part.

I can access the old cluster’s (`cosmos.lab.fiware.org`) headnode through SSH, but I cannot do it for the new cluster. I tried both `storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org` and `computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org` and failed to connect.

My intention in trying to connect via SSH was to test Hive queries on our data through the Hive CLI. After failing to do so, I checked and was able to connect to the 10000 port of `computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org` with telnet. I guess Hive is served through that port. Is this the only way we can use Hive in the new cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new pair of clusters have not enabled the ssh access. This is because users tend to install a lot of stuff (even not related with Big Data) in the “old” cluster, which had the ssh access enabled as you mention. So, the new pair of clusters are intended to be used only through the APIs exposed: WebHDFS for data I/O and Tidoop for MapReduce.

Being said that, a Hive Server is running as well and it should be exposing a remote service in the 10000 port as you mention as well. I say “it should be” because it is running an experimental authenticator module based in OAuth2 as WebHDFS and Tidoop do. Theoretically, connecting to that port from a Hive client is as easy as using your Cosmos username and a valid token (the same you are using for WebHDFS and/or Tidoop).

And what about a Hive remote client? Well, this is something your application should implement. Anyway, I have uploaded some implementation examples in the Cosmos repo. For instance:

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cosmos/tree/develop/resources/java/hiveserver2-client